# continue test execution after page timeout in ruby capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, timeout, automated-tests, capybara

I am using Ruby Capybara with Siteprims for my Selenium tests. In most cases my environment does not load the page completely because of the implicit wait for the DOM, causing tests to fail. In order to find the locators we use `find(locator).action`. In most cases the locators are already loaded but because the page is still spinning, Selenium is waiting to finish.

Is there any way to try to perform    `Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)` even if I get a timeout exception?

Comment: maybe changing the default timeout (to 90-120 seconds for example) could help? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#internal-timeouts

Comment: @fabersky my driver instance looks like this : ```   Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    client.read_timeout = 120
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, http_client: client)
  end
  Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
  Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 60 ``` , so looks like there is no difference

Comment: can you try to change `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` to 120?

Comment: Net::ReadTimeout isn't really going to be affected  by Capybara.default_max_wait_time - Your best bet is to use something like puffing_billy to block the requests for whatever resources are timing out during the page load (I assume they're third party resources where you're getting rate limited)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole that might be the case , we already have a query string ` disable_ads=1 ` that is automatically passed for each tests so we disable all potential ads that might try to be served on the page , I will try puffing-billy to see what I can get out of it , thanks for suggesting it